# Would like to display data without ngfor or console.log to the html view of angular component

Tags: angular, view

I would like to display the statement in my console log in my app.component.html rather than in the console. This is a very basic question I know but every example i've seen uses ng loops and stuff. I literally just want to learn hot display an object in the view without looping through it or doing unnecessary other stuff.

app.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


 declare function myMethod(): any;


 @Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
 })
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 title = 'my-learning-app';
```

sample.js

```
ngOnInit() {

myMethod(); // Function call
}

}
 sample.json
 let companies =[
 {
 "name" : "Big Corporation",
 "numberofEmployees" : 1000,
 "ceo" : "Mary",
 "rating": 3.6
 },
 {"name" : "Small Startup",
 "numberofEmployees" : 1000,
 "ceo" : "null",
 "rating" : 4.3
 }
 ]
 function myMethod(){
 console.log(companies[0].name)


 }
```

app.component.html

```
   <span>{{ companies }} app is running!</span>
```

Comment: So you want to display `companies[0].name` in your HTML?

Comment: That's exactly right. I don't want to use a for loop, I just want to get the basics down

Comment: Have you done the official tutorial yet? https://angular.io/tutorial It's a great starting point

Comment: I'll check it out later thanks

Comment: Is there an easy solution to do this very basic thing or must it be more verbose?

Comment: right now it's logging it to the console. I simply want to put that in the html

Comment: You're asking a question that could be answered by following any tutorial, so I won't do a full answer. I have created a working version of your example to give you a starting point. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x7vku4 I've done away with the `function() {}`, as we're now using classes. I would strongly recommend learning all of the fundamentals and playing around with any examples you can find. StackOverflow is not a tutorial site.

Comment: My array of companies is in a external javascript file declared in my app.component.ts file  on the seconde line    `declare function myMethod(): ` your stackblitz answer does not apply

Comment: Maybe "json" pipe would help. For example, {{ companies | json }}

Comment: Use the JsonPipe along with the `pre` tag for formatting like so `<pre>{{ companies | json }}</pre>`

Comment: @SerdarSayın. The examples that you guys give aren't working because It is more to do with the code than the html. The example Kurt gave works but it is for inline json. Currently my project uses a file from assets folder called sample.js which includes my method

Comment: @KurtHamilton How come when I try your example with my files it doesn't work. The only difference is my array is in a separate javascript file called sample.js. It should work as it works in stackblitz right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this **{{companies[0]?.name}}** in you html

Answer (score 0):

You must use the NgiF directive.  {{companies[0].name}}

[displaying data angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)